# ios9 UICollectionView issue, after rotating

Tags: uicollectionview, ios9, baker-framework

When I rotating my device (landscape or portrain), screen is half black. But when collectionView is empty (no cells), or It has few cells, all is ok. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found problem and workaround. The problem is in the method:

`-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`

I removed this method and now work fine.